# SQL assign infinite params

Tags: javascript, sql

Usually we will use SQL queries like below, we will pass params with predifined number **$1**

```
queryRunner.query('SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE code IN ($1)', ['1'])
```

But I want to pass multiple params without predifined **$1**. Any way to resolve this?

```
queryRunner.query('SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE code IN ($$)', ['1','2','3'])
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach dynamically builds the `IN` clause based on the expected number of parameters.  Consider:

```js
var params = ['1','2','3'];
var inClause = '?' + ', ?'.repeat(params.length - 1);
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE code IN (' + inClause + ')';
console.log(sql);
```

Once we have a statement with the right number of placeholders, we can simply bind the collection or array with no trouble.